# Remove node from Microk8s cluster

Tags: server, kubernetes, microk8s

I've dead node which I probably removed using `kubectl` instead of `microk8s` command. The problem is that `microk8s status` still shows it among *datastore standby nodes*. How can it be deleted from the cluster?

```
microk8s remove-node 192.168.1.3 --force
Error from server (NotFound): nodes "192.168.1.3" not found
Node 192.168.1.3 does not exist in Kubernetes.
```

Is it safe to remove the node from `/var/snap/microk8s/current/var/kubernetes/backend/cluster.yaml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it seems that works:

1. Adding a new node with the same name using `microk8s join`
2. This node is broken (microk8s is not running)
3. Remove the node from cluster by running `microk8s leave` at the node itself
4. If needed, the node with the same name can be added again and works

Answer (score 3):

On the (slave) node that you want remove from the cluster run:

```
microk8s leave
```

on the master node:

find the name of the node that you want to remove from the cluster:

```
microk8s.kubectl get nodes
```

then:

```
microk8s remove-node <name-of-the-node>
```